# What CSS property corresponds to Chrome's "scale" setting

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, scale

In Chrome's print dialog (under "advanced"), there is a "scale" setting.

[image: Chrome's print dialog's "scale" setting]

What CSS property maps to this setting?

Using this setting, I can adjust the scale of the content to be printed so that it wraps correctly. If I can determine the corresponding CSS property, I can define that scale in the print media rules.

I have tried `transform:scale(0.75);` and `zoom:75%;`, but neither setting seems to behave the same way.

Comment: i would say scale(1) for 100 and so on .. did you try this ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif "I have tried `transform:scale(0.75);` and `zoom:75%;` "

Comment: i know, but 0.75 for which value ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif `html{ transform:scale(0.75); }`

Comment: you didn't get me ... when you set 0.75 what is the value you would use within the Chrome parametre ? my quesiton is "are you doing a good matching of values" ?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. When in Chrome's print dialog, a "scale" of "75" makes my content wrap correctly. If I then set that to "100", and tried the CSS rules, the content does not scale the same way.

Comment: Though I'm not sure, It wouldn't surprise me it's doing something to the base font-size of your page. How responsive is your website in the browser? How does it scale if you make your browser window "page-sized"?

Comment: @vandijkstef the page in question uses Bootstrap 2.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Think @page size is what you're looking for.

Try something like:

```
@page {
  size: a5;
}
```

From my quick testing, I don't think % values will work, but [vw](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#vw) will.

Comment: Isn't "vw" a percentage-based value?

Comment: @JeromyFrench - yes, it is.  What I meant was, that a straight % value (e.g. size: 75%) won't work - at least not in the context of what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use the @page rule? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40page)

> updated

And try to use the decimal point instead of percentage. For example:

```
body {
  transform: scale(.75);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

@page {
   size: a5;
}
```